# Dynamic memory allocation. What am I missing?

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, malloc

Please take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* foo = (char*)malloc(500000000);

    // when I uncomment stuff that's below then operating system
    // admits that this program uses 500MB of memory. If I keep
    // this commented, it claims that the program uses almost no
    // memory at all. Why is it so?

    /*
    for (int i=0; i<500000000; i++)
    {
        foo[i] = (char)i;
    }
    */

    int bar; scanf("%d", &bar); // wait so I can see what's goin on

    free(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

My intuition is simple. When I allocate 500MB with malloc call then OS should say that the process is using over 500MB of memory. But apparently, it doesn't work that way. What am I missing? What trick is OS using, what should I read about?

Thank you in advance for any clues.

Comment: It's probably the compiler, not the OS, using a trick called optimization.

Comment: What OS? AFAIK linux usually uses overcommit: that is it returns you an address in your address space that is not yet backed up by physical memory, until you first access it.

Comment: btw, this is C and not C++.

Comment: Also note that 1MB == 1024KB == 1048576B, 500000000B is 476.8MB

Comment: When you say "the OS says the process is using n bytes of memory?" what metric are you talking about?  People use "memory" to mean (1) virtual address space (2) virtual bytes private to a particular process (3) physical memory (4) page file reserved space, (5) page file committed space, and half a dozen other things. It is entirely possible that you're looking at the wrong metric in the first place.

Comment: Please stop it @DaveHillier! 1MB == 1000KB == 1000000B! Christ, this is one of very few things that pisses me off just so much. Read up on this **ASAP**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: @gustaf r what does the OS report, is it binary or base 10? How much memory is he allocating? He's expecting 500MB

Comment: @DaveHillier My version of `du` has this in the manual: *--si like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024*. 1000 versus 1024 is the very reason the "mebibyte" appeared. That said, both 1000 and 1024 can be right, used consistently.

Comment: @DaveHillier what is most important? To be right, or to make the same mistakes everybody else does? 1KB == 1000B, and you can **NEVER** change that. In computer science, we usually calculate with 1024, which is why it has its own prefix. 1KiB == 1024B. Read up on the link, please. And spread the word, so that the madness of destroying SI units can end **asap**.

Comment: @gustafr If a user is in Windows, and he checks the Task Manager, what does the postfix, MB and KB mean?

Comment: @gustafr What is more important? To be pedantically right or to talk in a way that others understand you? SI units are just a convention, to make sure people understand each other. Bytes (unfortunately) use a different convention.

Comment: It's a matter of convention so if there is a doubt, always specify what you mean so we can all understand each other. EOT. :)

Answer (score 7):

> What am I missing? What trick is OS using, what should I read about

It's a form of lazy allocation. In a nutshell:

- `malloc` asks the OS for a lot of memory and the OS goes: "sure, here you go" and does (almost) nothing
- the OS secretly hopes you never touch the "allocated" pages
- when you *do* touch an allocated page, the OS catches the inevitable page fault, sighs and allocates the page

This happens per-page. So you'll get the same usage if in your `for` you increment `i` by the page size on your system (likely 4096 or something like that). As a simple trick, try playing with the number of elements the `for` touches. As a bonus, try to predict the memory usage by dividing the size by the size of the page

Comment: @chomzee Don't take my word for it. Try it out and see if things really happen that way.

Comment: One thing makes me wonder. What if OS has no place for such lazy allocation when I 'touch' some fragment of virtual memory? `malloc` already succeded and returned the value. Will the program crash?

Comment: @chomzee I think the OS wouldn't give it to you in the first place. At any rate, if at all possible, it will try to swap something out to make room. But again, I don't think it oversubscribes.

Comment: Most operating systems do oversubscribe. (Such as MS WIndows, Linux and Darwin) This is also the reasone malloc virtually never fails on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @FUZxxl Well, looks like I'll have to look into it one of these days. I believe you, but I would like some sort of reference or quote.

Comment: Try writing a program for amd64 that allocates 1 TiB of memory. It usually succeeds in doing so, but receives a signal when the system can't allocate any more pages to it.

Comment: @cnicutar Apparently, you can control the overcommitment behavior under linux. See link. http://fuz.su/~fuz/overcommit.c

Comment: @FUZxxl Haha, real nice! Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 2):

All memory usage in a process is virtualized by the OS.  You might be "allocating" a memory block in your code, but the OS might not actually be committing it to physical memory until it is actually used by the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your OS is likely not allocating (or showing that it has allocated) the memory until you use it.

In any case, checking the return value of `malloc()` is a pretty good idea if you're gonna allocate such large chunks. `malloc()` **can** fail, you know.

Comment: I know malloc can fail. But it doesn't seem like it's the case since I also tried:
    foo[0] = 0;
    foo[4999...9] = 0;
and it also claims that proces uses very few memory.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system memory pages are only really allocated to your process when you access them (by writing, in your case). The exact behavior depends on you compiler and OS - on a different system you might find that the memory is used up immediately.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with OS. The compiler optimizes the resulting code such that if the allocated memory is not used then it removes the statement that allocates the memeory in the resulting binary. You can check this by setting your compilers optimization level to zero. Then you will get 500MB in either case because the memory will be allocated every time.